# handling things outside of main loop in PyQt4

Tags: python, qt, loops, pyqt4

We're building a hardware thing based on RaspberryPi and using PyQt4 to handle output on a small 3" screen.

Apart from screen we have a simple hardware keypad that needs handling in a loop to check for keys pressed and act accordingly.

To simplify things code right now looks something like this:

```
while True:
        gui_initialized = False
        current_screen = None
        if gui_initialized is False:
            app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
            main_win = gui.GUI()
            gui_initialized = True
            sys.exit(app.exec_())

        key_code = kp.getKey()
```

This code is wrong because of the PyQt4 main loop. Once execution gets to the  line `sys.exit(app.exec_())` - it stops in there forever and never gets to `key_code = kp.getKey()`. But I need `key_code = kp.getKey()` to execute somewhere within the loop to handle keypad and also will need to do other background work.

In fact usual Qt event handling is not really applicable in our case because we'll have no standard input tools, only a custom keypad and NFC antenna, both handled within main python program.

So the question is - how do I handle additional work I need to do along with PyQt4 main loop?

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic way of doing polling in Qt is to put your polling code in a slot, and connect to it a timeout signal from a `QTimer` with a zero timeout.

Comment: after all I've got rid of exec_() call and implemented required actions of Qt main loop inside my main loop explicitly. There are just two function calls in fact.

Comment: Still, if you run something on *every turn* of the event loop, then zero-timeout timer is made precisely for this purpose.